# Outlook returns undefined error when running macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this macro.. and almost every time it returns an undefined error, and sometimes it works normally.. I believe it has some error, or is missing some closure that I don't know.. could someone help me

```
Public Sub Test(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

Dim sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ArquivosEmail\"

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments

oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName

Next


Shell "wscript C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Envios\test.vbs", vbNormalFocus

 

 

 

End Sub
```

Comment: What should happen when the filename already exists?

Answer (score 0):

I just added an error handler, try to get more info on whats going on.

I also ensure `oAttachment.Type = olByValue`  , there are some exceptional Types you can't save as a file.

```
    Public Sub Test(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String

    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ArquivosEmail\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        If oAttachment.Type = olByValue Then
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.FileName
        End If
    Next

    Shell "wscript C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Envios\test.vbs", vbNormalFocus

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olattachmenttype

Comment: I believe it is some error in the macro or in the outlook itself.. because it returns in the message box "error:" and nothing else

Comment: as always it's just an attachment I'll try to change the code to save the first item

Comment: Change or empty the destination folder to be sure is not conflicting name as someone commented above